# how to bulk remove the name in my list with regex

Tags: regex

I have many bbm pin list
and I want to delete all the names with the red line on the list in bulk using regex?
[image]

Sample:

5e357935 JANCOK
51de9aa7 ASU
5AB88ECD
570E997E
570E997E COK
5D026965
5787B95A
5B0502DB
5bbb3c33 NGNTOD
7C60CE59
5815E544
5EA4EA57 KIRIK
5EBA3A6A
5ec0c768 PELER
5F6E8BEC
5F553830
5EA4EA57
5a476122 DOMBA

Comment: image only is frowned up..put the example string here along with your attempt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]Can you please replace the image with code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image.

Comment: "Remove" using what? An editor, programming language...?

Comment: using regex code, in regex101.com

Comment: **[check](https://regex101.com/r/nL3lV5/1)**

Comment: ok thanks ^ why you not fill in answer box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture in the question looks suspiciously a screenshot from [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

In that case one can do it directly in that editor via a Replace All.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
:g/ /d
```

That's a vim (ex) command, which says "delete every line that contains a space".

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're on Notepad++, I'd use the following search/replace :

search " .*$" (a space followed by any characters up to the end of the line)
replace by "" (the empty string)